# Fastest way to generate 2D Gaussian

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, array-broadcasting

I am trying to generate an asymmetric 2D Gaussian with dim 7x7, but I want to do it as fast as possible. I have tried 4 different ways:

```
x=np.arange(7)[None].astype(np.float); y=x.T
xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x,y)
mx,my,sx,sy=3.0,4.0,1.0,2.0 #centre and width params
gauss=np.exp(-(xx-mx)**2/sx-(yy-my)**2/sy) #full grid
gauss=np.exp(-(x-mx)**2/sx-(y-my)**2/sy) #x and y vectors
gauss=np.exp(-(y-my)**2/sy)*(np.exp(-(x-mx)**2/sx)) #multiplication
gauss=np.exp(-(y-my)**2/sy).dot(np.exp(-(x-mx)**2/sx)) #dot product
```

Benchmarks on my computer with %timeit:

```
#full grid: 13.4 us
#x,y vectors: 16.5 us
#multiplication: 17.7 us
#dot prod: 16.5
```

I am surprised the fastest approach is the one using the full grid. Also, generating this full grid is not an issue since it will be reused for many computations. Is there any faster way to compute `gauss`?

Comment: Test on bigger sized arrays?

Comment: Do you mind random values?

Comment: @Divakar Ok, I just tried with larger arrays (`700` instead of  `7`), `multiplication` and `dot` are much faster (more than one order of magnitude), that's what I was expecting.  However, I want performance because I need to generate `7x7` arrays numerous times, instead of one large array :(

Comment: @kabanus `gauss` must be generated with specific `params: mx, my, sx, sy`, not random values

Comment: I mean, do you want the function evaluated on a specific grid? Do you just want a callable you can use, is any dense grid OK?

Comment: @kabanus By dense grid do you mean `xx` and `yy`? `xx` and `yy` are the same for all `gauss`, only `params` change. Regarding `xx` and `yy` values, I can use any value for them, but `params` would have to change accordingly

Comment: Do you have to produce those patches one by one or can you work in bulk?

Comment: @PaulPanzer One by one, it's for fitting data, so `params` get updated in each iteration and a new `gauss` is computed

Comment: Not sure, but as most of your cost seem to be overheads, not actual computation, Cython may be an option.

Comment: There is a chance to vectorize what you're describing in the comments. Could you edit the question with your full problem? I don't think you can improve much the small problem you asked about.